# What is Monero "dust"?

Tags: transaction-fees

I've seen the term "dust" used for small amounts of Monero. What is the maximum value threshold for an amount to be considered dust?

Comment: I used this question as a segue to answering my first question. If there is a better explanation, I'm looking forward to reading it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I consider "dust" to be any amount of Monero not exceeding the cost of the transaction fee, therefore nullifying its value.